# Рендеринг блока сообщений в чате

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, angular

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую Angular, и через async pipe вывожу сообщения в контейнер чата. Нужно реализовать группировку сообщений по дням (как на картинке). Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать ?

Comment: в rx есть оператор `groupBy`, который принимает параметром предикат группировки. Если у тебя все сообщения в массиве, то можешь их сгруппировать по дате и еще запайпить через `toArray` (в доке есть пример). Из 1 массива ты получишь несколько сгруппированных массивов, дальше можешь замаппить этот массив массивов на объект, где ключами будет дата, а значением сообщения, что-то типа `{ 'Wd 18-09-2019': [ ....messages ]`. Опять же это просто псевдокод да и посредственное решение проблемы, на быструю руку так сказать, чтоб сказать что-то конкретное нужно видеть _воспроизводимый пример_

Comment: Привет, опять ты меня выручаешь :) Решение попробую. У меня вообще ни какого не было :( Да же не знал, с какой стороны к нему подходить :) Как запилю, поделюсь результатом, ну или возникшими трудностями. Спасибо

Comment: @overthesanity Попробовал я твой метод, все шикаргно работает. `groupBy` формирует группы по дате,  а `mergeMap`  и `toArray` шикарно формируют массив с массивоми сгруппированных объектов. После внутренней логики `rxjs reduce` возмращает мне мой массив объектов с нужными мне изменениями. Но есть нюанс, а имеено  `groupBy` не работает с массивами... по этому когда тестировал, пришлось внутри `map` разбивать массив на поток при помощи `for` и в этом `pipe` применять все изложенное выше...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил таким вот образом.

```
messages.reduce((prev, curr, index, arr) => {
      let prevObj = index - 1;
      if (curr.formatedDate == arr[prevObj].formatedDate) {} else {
        arr[prevObj].groupDate = arr[prevObj].formatedDate
      }
      return arr;
```

Передаю массив в фукцию, где у каждого обьекта сравниваю время. Если время отличается, то предыдущему обьекту добавляю поле с предыдущим временем. И это поле рендерю в чате. НА выходе из функцию получаю свой же массив, но уже с нужными мне изменениями. И такая функцию отлично работает и с пагинацией и с подключением webSocket'ов.